# keycloak - endpoint for register new user

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

How to register a new user without passing by admin, keycloak offer an interface to register a new user
URL for registering new users in the browser directly :

> http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/myrealm/login-actions/registration?client_id=clientid&tab_id=tab-id

But I don't find the endpoints of the rest API of registration.
I succeeded to add a user using admin rest API but I want to register a new user without mentioning the token of admin.

Answer (score 1):

You can't register users in keycloak without adding a token, but what you can do is add a middleware as a service that takes simple users details as a body and then register from that service, i already implemented this middleware here
[Keycloak middleware to register users asking for token](https://github.com/BendabizAdam/keycloak-users-extension)